# Custom Validation Error Popups Asp.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an Asp.Net MVC 4 application in which i am currently doing both Client side(JQuery) and server side validations.
Currently i use in my View
`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SomeField)` and it's working fine showing a red message on top of my control "This field is required" .

For Client side i implement IClientValidatable and its working fine too.

But , I would like to use some custom error message notification similiar to what Stackoverflow is doing, such as showing a tipped div near the control, with the error message.

Is there any JQuery  plugins availabile that i can use for this purpose.
I did some google search and i was not able to find any !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I've used before and would recommend [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/) JQuery plugin.

Check out some of the [demos](http://qtip2.com/demos)

I've found it works well with MVC and unobtrusive validation

Comment: Thanks ! So all i have to do is to write this code ?$('form').validate({ errorPlacement: function(error, element) { // qTip call $(element).not('.valid').qtip(); }, success: function(error) { // Hide tooltips on valid elements setTimeout(function() { myForm.find('.valid').qtip('hide'); }, 1); } });